# Fixed element width changes

Tags: css, fixed

The nav in the sidebar changes the width once the fixed class is added upon scrolling to that element. Depending on the screen width, it changes significantly.

http://festiva.com/fac.php

```
<div class="col-sm-4 nav_cnt">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="destinations2.php">Overview </a></li>
        <li><a class="current"href="fac.php">Festiva Adventure Club <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Festiva Weeks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Festiva Exchange Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Voyages by RTX</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Festiva Sailing Vacations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .nav_cnt{
        position: relative;
    }
    .fixed{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        width: inherit;
        width: 25%;
    }
}

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.nav_cnt').offset().top - 50 ) {
            $('.nav_cnt').find('.nav').addClass('fixed');
        }else{
            $('.nav_cnt').find('.nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
```

Comment: still searching the question, where it is?

Answer (score 0):

I would just find a good width for this sidebar nav and give it an explicit set width until mobile. This way you know it'll stay consistent and won't change widths at all. `280px` seemed good to me as I was testing and I set the `.nav_cnt` to a `col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3` instead so the content gets pushed closer to that sidebar nav. Try that out and see if you like the look of that.

Comment: Thats not too bad, but Im trying avoid the sudden width change upon scroll.

Comment: I would just set that sidebar nav to 280px even when it is not fixed @ThomasGrauer

Answer (score 0):

Search this in your `main.css` and make this changes and try.

```
@media handheld, only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .nav_cnt{
        position: relative;

    }
    .fixed{
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        width:26.65%;
    }
}
```